# How to access values from changeSets of Jenkins build in ruby script

Tags: ruby, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jira

I'm writing a JenkinsFile in which I have to load a ruby script which adds labels and comments to Jira tickets which are fixed in the current build. To do this I need commit-msg from git which contains Jira ticket number. ChangeSets of Jenkins contains commit-msg as {entry.msg}. How can I pass this entry.msg to my ruby script?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a changeset for that, because for a failed build, the changeset is there but you most likely don't want to update anything, and if you rebuild the changeset is empty. We use a different job that is triggered on success of an "official" build.

Answer (score 0):

don't rely on Jenkins Changeset, use a good old sh command. Changeset would behave weird when used with shared libraries